# LaunchServices logs XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED in mac os x console

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, launchd, launch-services

1.Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds
2.LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database database
launchservices: database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying

I found this two logs related to my Application in console those logs are generated at every 10 seconds.
I search about it but didn’t get proper reason
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7263229?tstart=0
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16788

Any idea about this logs? Any help would be useful

Comment: Please provide reason of down-vote. what is wrong in this question so i can improve my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1st warning please check all launch service(lauchchd) commands, And check which command cause this logs. please provide more logs relative to first warning.
(by restart your machine may stop log this warning)